# Will two 18650s in parallel double the total max continuous discharge current?

Tags: batteries

Let's say a 18650 cell is rated at max continuous discharge of 8A . Will having two in parallel make it 16A?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the two cells are **exactly** the same...exactly the same voltage, exactly the same internal resistance, exactly the same discharge curve...then yes, the maximum continuous discharge will be equal to the sum of the separate discharge values.

However, if the cells are not **exactly** the same you will not achieve double the current and you risk damaging one of the cells or causing a fire.

Comment: How strict are the requirements really, like can they be 5% of each other?

Comment: You want ideal results so you need ideal cells. How much loss of power can you tolerate? How worried are you about fire? That's how strict the requirements are.

Comment: Got it, thank you so much!